# How can I add a column with the amount of items I loan?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework, datagridview, many-to-many

I want to add a column with the amount of items that that person has lend
Thanks in advance

```
BindingSource bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();

bindingSource1.DataSource = (from l in db.Loans.Where(item => item.Items.Any())
                                         from i in db.Items.Where(loan => loan.Loans.Contains(l))
                                         from p in db.People.Where(person => person.Id == l.PersonId)
                                         select new
                                         {
                                             p.FirstName,
                                             l.LoanId,
                                             i.ItemId,
                                             i.ItemName
                                         }).ToList();


            dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
```

My result:

[image: result]

Comment: What have you tried?  How do you know the number of items someone has on loan?  These are the kinds of things we need to see in order to better help you.

Comment: I have tried "l.Items.Count " but this gives me the amout of time a item is displayed in my datagridview

I also have tried "  from c in db.Items.SelectMany(c => c.Loans).Distinct().Count() "
I try to implement expamples from forums but fail everytime, I'm already looking for this for 2 days, and everything works fine except showing amount of Items that is loaned

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find anything on the web, like... anything that actually worked!
So I edited my database --> I added a column to my "between table", I added QuantityLoaned

[My database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jFei.png)

Then I had to change a few things to my code, now it looks like this:

```
BindingSource bindingSource1 = new BindingSource();

bindingSource1.DataSource = (from l in db.LoanItems.Where(item => item.Item.LoanItems.Any())
                                         from p in db.People.Where(person => person.Id == l.Loan.PersonId)
                                         orderby l.LoanId ascending
                                         select new
                                         {
                                             p.Id,
                                             p.FirstName,
                                             l.LoanId,
                                             l.Item.ItemId,
                                             Dagenoud = SqlFunctions.DateDiff("Weekday", l.Loan.StartDate, DateTime.Now),
                                             l.QuantityLoaned
                                         }).ToList();


            dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
```

This gives me the next result:

[My result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMDYi.png)